# Setting Manager path in Tomcat6

Tags: tomcat

I want to switch context path to Manager app in Tomcat6
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html

I change $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/manager.xml to:

```
<Context path="/adm" docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" antiJARLocking="false">
```

notice to: **path="/adm"**, but manager app is always in **/manager**.

Please, how can I change manager path in Tomcat6?
Thanks a lot.
Tom

Comment: Need to restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename manager.xml to be adm.xml